# Ntile usage in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

I need to compare last year sales and current year sales based on quintile score and should divide all the customers into 1,2,3,4,5 buckets using NTILE function.
Also need to include 2 more columns(old,new) in the report.

Old indicates customers who comes under 1,2,3,4,5 buckets in previous year but not purchased in current year.

New indicates customers who comes under 1,2,3,4,5 buckets in current year but not purchased in previous year.

For this i have created two custom groups one for previous year and other for current year.

In each custom group i have created 5 filters for 1,2,3,4,5 buckets and in one custom group i have included one more filter for old and in another custom group i have included filter for new.

In report results old and new columns are missing and remaining 1,2,3,4,5 values are getting for previous and current year in form of matrix(6*6).

Comment: can you show an example of what should look like the final result?

Comment: the below mentioned template should be the final result

Comment: suppose in previous year, we have customer id's 1,2,3,4,5 and got 1,2,3,4,5 ranks respectively. 
  In current year we have customer id's 1,2,3,6,7 and got  1,2,3,4,5 ranks.

Comment: customer id 1 should come under 1 bucket.  
  customer id 2 should come under 2 bucket.   customer id 3 should come under 3 bucket.
  customer id's 4,5 should come under old column as they didn't purchase anything in current year. 
  customer id's 6,7 should come under new column as they didn't purchase anything in previous year...

Comment: customers who are common in current and previous years should come under 1,2,3,4,5 bucktes.
  customers who purchased previously and  didn't purchase anything currently comes under old.
  customers who purchased currently and  didn't purchase anything previously comes under old.

Comment: the best thing is to update the question with an example of final result, use the blockcode functionality or attach a screenshot

Comment: How to add screenshot? there is no option available...

Comment: if you edit your question you will see a button to add images. Check also this: [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: i have edited the question and added image but it is throwing error(need atleast 10 reputations to add an image)